# Camera Intent - how to?

Tags: android, android-camera

Sorry to bother you guys, but I am not able to get a solution where In we take picture using intents. I know the default behavior of native camera is to save the picture at default directory/place of O.S. The thing is I have some requirements where I do not want to save the picture when clicked using camera app. There has to be a solution of this issue, be it like once we take a picture we could delete it right away, or there should be an alternate by which we won't allow O.S to save Image, please help.

Here is a piece of code I tried, tried several ways by creating a directory and then deleting file, nothing works.

```
 public void takeImageFromCamera() {

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }


  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

// Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (isCameraPermissionGranted()) {
                bitmap= (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
              //  bitmap = processReuiredImage(picUri);
                getProfileDetailViaFace(encodeImageBitmapToString(bitmap));
                Log.d("path",String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)));

              //  getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(, "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures", null);
            //     mediaStorageDir.getPath().delete();


            } else {
                requestCameraPermission();
            }
        }

public void takeImageFromCamera() {

    File file = getOutputMediaFile(CAMERA_FILE_TYPE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        try {

            Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
            m.invoke(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    picUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Intent takePictureIntent = new 
   Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }
    }

   private File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    mediaStorageDir  = new 
     File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "peppercard");

    /**Create the storage directory if it does not exist*/
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**Create a media file name*/
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    if (type == CAMERA_FILE_TYPE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpeg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

}
        return mediaFile;

}

Comment: i think you have to make your own camera, don't use intent

Comment: As you do not want the file to be visible in the Gallery app you should use private internal storage instead of external storage as you do now.

Comment: Further you have to use a file provider then. Without not possible.

Comment: Then remove the shamefull strictmode code lines.

Comment: You need another onActivityResult() too.

Comment: okay let me try it

Answer (score 2):

> The thing is I have some requirements where I do not want to save the picture when clicked using camera app

The decision of whether or not to save an image is up to the camera app, not you. There are hundreds of camera apps that might respond to `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and the developers of those apps can do whatever they want.

> There has to be a solution of this issue, be it like once we take a picture we could delete it right away, or there should be an alternate by which we won't allow O.S to save Image,

Take the photo yourself, using the camera APIs or libraries that wrap around them (e.g., CameraKit-Android, Fotoapparat).

Comment: Thank you for your response, so it seems I have to implement the custom camera, like using surfaceHolder and other things.

Comment: @user8754981: Again, third-party libraries like those that I mentioned will simplify this, handling things like `SurfaceView`/`TextureView` for you.

Comment: Another thing is, I have used the same code in Moto G3, v-6.0 and same using in lenovo tablet, v6.0, when clicking an image using moto the Image does not save, but the tablet does. So I was wondering there has to be a way out to solve the issue with tablet.

Comment: @user8754981: No, insofar as the developers of the Lenovo camera app can do whatever they want. They can save the photos. They can upload the photos to a server somewhere. It is their app, not yours.

Comment: I end up by creating a custom camera using surface view only, that way the picture isn't saving in internal or external memory, only opening the camera and sending it directly to the server, discarding saving the picture in directory, that's the best solution I could think off.

Answer (score 0):

```
There has to be a solution of this issue, be it like once we take  
a picture we could delete it right away
```

Indeed there is. You could specify a path (even using a file provider) where the camera app has to put the image in a file.

Then when the camera app is done you can get the image from that file and then delete the file.

Have a look at `Intent.EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Pretty standard your question. You can find a lot of example code on this site.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to delete the picture in on activity result by, getContentResolver().delete(picUri,null, null);, but It does not find the correct url, end up with exception.

Comment: However, " You could specify a path (even using a file provider) where the camera app has to put the image in a file." I can do that, but It only deletes the file from the external directory that I have created, It doesnot delete the file from the gallery.

Comment: I have searched over and over but nothing seems to work, tried with extra output as well, but it still saving the file, any quick solution where an image wont save in gallery? However I can only think of creating custom camera so that I can manage it by my own

Comment: Of course it is making a file. Thats what i said isnt it? But you can delete it as soon as you want. And it does not save in gallery -whatever that is- but in the storage you indicate.

Comment: Do it in private storage so other apps have no access. Also no gallery access.

Comment: You did not use a file prover i think as using a file provider will not directly make files visible in the Gallery app. And certainly never when using internal memory.

Comment: For deleting the file you did not have to use the content resolver. Using the File class on the file path would have done. I dont know if FileProvider implemented the delete ok or you used it wrong.

Comment: I have tried using creating directory as well, but in this case, It creates a file in gallery and in external directory as well

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time when I posted a code here, let me repost it.

Answer (score 0):

Final I have found the answer after waiting from past 2 days, yay..It will not save the file as I am just deleting the file after returning from  the activity.

String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,                                projection, null, null, null)

int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
 cursor.moveToLast();

```
                    String imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath );
                    Log.d("bitmapImage", bitmapImage.toString());                       /*delete file after taking picture*/
                    Log.d("imagePath", imagePath.toString());
                    File f = new File(imagePath);
                    if (f.exists()){
                        f.delete();

                    }
```

sendBroadcast(newIntent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,Uri.fromFile(f)));